# Realm Sandbox OS X Issue

Tags: swift, macos, realm

I just received an app rejection with the following reason:

> The application accesses the following location(s):
>
> '/Applications/myappname/Contents/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/Versions/A/Resources/en.lproj'
>
> The majority of developers encountering this issue are opening files in Read/Write mode instead of Read-Only mode, in which case it should be changed to Read-Only.
>
> Other common reasons for this issue include:
>
> - creating or writing files in the above location(s), which are not valid locations for files to be written as stated in documentation
> - writing to the above location(s) without using a valid app-id as a container for the written files

The path to my realm file is
`/Users/john/Library/Containers/myapp/Data/Library/Application Support/default.realm`

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm doesn't read or write to its framework location. Is this something your code, or another library, might be doing?

Comment: How could I debug this? Which tool should l use to see file access?

Comment: I received nothing back from that breakpoint. Is there other aliases?

Comment: you could listen to file system events, using something like [watch](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/watch.rb)

Comment: uh, I meant [fswatch](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/fswatch.rb)